# IndexError when calling list inside list

Tags: python, pygame

I am very new to python and am trying to make a game of chess using pygame. For the positions of the pieces (specifically the first pawn) I have a list inside a list that references an index in the first list. Later on when this listception is called to I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when they definitely are in range... was hoping someone with a bit of knowledge could explain this?

I can't think of another way to assign the positions of the pieces to their variables, and the error isn't exactly accurate so I honestly have no clue.

```
pawnA2 = [WHITE_PAWN, 1, 2]
pawnA2 == [WHITE_PAWN, 1, 2, [(pawnA2[1]), (pawnA2[2] + 1)]]
```

200 lines later...

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if ((pawnA2[1] - 1) * 100 + 5 ) < event.pos[0] < (pawnA2[1] * 100 + 5 ) and (8 - pawnA2[2]) * 100 + 5 < event.pos[1] < (((8 - pawnA2[2]) + 1) * 100 + 5 ):
            print("yes")
            screen.blit(MOVABLE_SPACE,(((pawnA2[3][0]) - 1) * 100 + 30, (8 - pawnA2[3][1]) * 100 + 30))
        else:
            screen.blit(third_surface,(5, 505))
update_screen()
```

the line referenced in the error is:

```
screen.blit(MOVABLE_SPACE,(((pawnA2[3][0]) - 1) * 100 + 30, (8 - pawnA2[3][1]) * 100 + 30))
```

Comment: Split the statement into multiple statements so you can tell which part if causing the error.

Comment: `x = ((pawnA2[3][0]) - 1) * 100 + 30` `y = (8 - pawnA2[3][1]) * 100 + 30` `screen.blit(MOVABLE_SPACE, (x, y))`

Comment: You have a `==` instead of `=` in the `pawnA2` assignment

Comment: *"I get "IndexError: list index out of range" when they definitely are in range"* - No, if you get that error then the index is definitely *out* of range. The computer is not wrong about this, you are; you have to accept that before you start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `==` instead of `=` in the `pawnA2` assignment, resulting in a statement that evaluates to false without changing `pawnA2`